# Building cloud service using python google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

Hi i'm trying to make my own cloud web service that uses python google drive API.

what i'm trying to make is basically cloud service but can also interact with Google Drive.

To do that, my web service users have to have their own 'storage.json' file in their server's virtual directory (which really stores in server).

[image: server's directory looks like this]

when I somehow get my own 'storage.json' file, (I followd: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

and upload 'storage.json' file to my directory like User1, upload and download with Google drive works just fine.

but my final goal is when my user doesn't have 'storage.json' file in their directory like User2, I want browser to pops up in User2's computer and User2 can follow the google's authentication flow and finally download 'storage.json' file into server's ~/User2/ directory.

Do you think this is possible? or if there are better ways, can you notice me? thank you

Comment: What is storage.json exactly?

Comment: storage.json stores your current Google Drive status. so it is basically works as your own key file.